# Replenish internal sensors when the computers are offline

Tags: the-captain-is-dead

When the computer is offline, we have no skill deck. I assume this impacts the crew (e.g. the tactical officer) when their ability says to draw from the skill deck in certain situations.
What I can’t find explicitly documented however, is where the internal sensors are replenished from.
[image]
If the computer is offline, can the internal sensors be replenished from the skills discard?
There is no other instance I know of where one system going offline cripples another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal sensors do draw cards from the skill deck as needed to ensure that there are always 3 cards available when it and the computers are online. Once the computers go offline the cards that are currently in the internal sensors remain but there is no longer any skills for it to draw.

The rules are pretty bad about explaining how all the systems work but in this case the card itself talks about drawing cards and the only place you draw cards from is the skill deck which can't be done when there is no skill deck do to the computer being offline.

The reason why you don't see any other examples of one system directly impacting another is because the other systems are not as closely related as these two are in dealing with the same end result (skill card) in a slightly different manner.